# ApplicationInsigths.config being ignored

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

It looks like that the `ApplicationInsights.config` file in my application is being ignored because:

- I've set `MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond` to 1, yet, it's still flooding
- I've changed the `TelemetryChannel` to a custom one, and it's stopping at breakpoints, neither behaving as I expected

Is there something i'm missing? perhaps a reference to the file somewhere?

my goal is to implement: http://apmtips.com/blog/2015/05/06/diy-data-sampling/ (but not sampling, but filtering out some traces and etc)

**Edit1:** perhaps this is something that is supposed to be ignored on dev environment?

Comment: is the spelling correct with the file?  Otherwise it looks like you might have a typo with `ApplicationInsights.config`

Comment: yes, its my typo here... in the solution the name is correct (generated by the nuget package itself)

Comment: gotcha - just making sure :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the `/bin/` directory in the same directory and made sure that there is no "phantom" file there?  I found something (actually on the same site as the one you linked above) that shows the search order looks there first.

Take a look here: http://apmtips.com/blog/2014/12/23/applicationinsights-dot-config-file-search-order/ for what I found.

Comment: that solved the issue of my channel's breakpoints not being hit... but not all of my problems =(... tks a lot anyway!